# Dynamic Visibility of menu item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsix

In my VS extension I need to add menu item for my new project type. But I want it to show for my custom type only. So I added this code to .vcst file:

```
  <Button guid="_Interactive_WindowCmdSet" id="cmdidLoadUI" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="_Interactive_WindowCmdSet" id="ProjectItemMenuGroup" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
    <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Load</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>


  <Group  guid="_Interactive_WindowCmdSet" id="ProjectItemMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE"/>
  </Group>
```

And added this code to package initialization:

```
            // Create the command for the menu item.
            CommandID projectMenuCommandID = new CommandID(GuidList.Interactive_WindowCmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidLoadUI);
            OleMenuCommand projectmenuItem = new OleMenuCommand(LoadUIMenuItemCallback, projectMenuCommandID);
            projectmenuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += projectmenuItem_BeforeQueryStatus;
            mcs.AddCommand(projectmenuItem);
```

And query status handler is:

```
    private void projectmenuItem_BeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleMenuCommand menuCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;

        if (menuCommand != null)
            menuCommand.Visible = IsProjectOfRightType(GetSelected<Project>());
    }
```

The problem is - this status handler never get called. So I have this menu item showed for all project types.

I've tried also to implement `IOleCommandTarget` interface on my package, like:

```
    public int QueryStatus(ref Guid guidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
    {
        // Disable all commands in case if project is VisuaART project, otherwise - disable them.
        OLECMDF cmdf;

        for (int i = 0; i < cCmds; i++)
        {
            var command = prgCmds[i];
            if (command.cmdID == PkgCmdIDList.cmdidLoadUI)
            {
                if (IsProjectOfRightType(GetSelected<Project>()))
                    command.cmdf = (uint)COMMAND_SUPPORTED;
                else
                    command.cmdf = (uint)COMMAND_UNSUPPORTED;
            }

        }
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    private const OLECMDF COMMAND_SUPPORTED = OLECMDF.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED | OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED;
    private const OLECMDF COMMAND_UNSUPPORTED = OLECMDF.OLECMDF_INVISIBLE;
```

But that doesn't helped either. Method is called, but setting `OLECMDF.OLECMDF_INVISIBLE` does nothing. What should I do to hide this menu item for unsupported menu items?

Answer (score 9):

Probably the problem is related with the load of the Package. To load the Package automatically just add this attribute to your Package Class:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad("f1536ef8-92ec-443c-9ed7-fdadf150da82")]
```

Ex.:

```
.
.
[ProvideAutoLoad("f1536ef8-92ec-443c-9ed7-fdadf150da82")]
public sealed class MyPackageTest : Package
{
.
.
```

When you don’t add this attribute your class will be loaded just when you click on any button of your Package.

I hope I have helped.

Comment: See the UI Context GUID possibilities here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166496.aspx
Note that we can see the GUID above on this page, and it means UICONTEXT_SolutionExists.

Answer (score 2):

In case it's applicable, Microsoft recommends using [rule-based UI contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-rule-based-ui-context-for-visual-studio-extensions) when auto-loading packages:

> Loading packages can have a performance impact and loading them sooner than needed is not the best practice. Visual Studio 2015 introduced the concept of Rules-based UI Contexts, a mechanism that allows extension authors to define the precise conditions under which a UI Context is activated and associated VSPackages are loaded.

I've only ever used this strategy to show menu items for specific *file* types (here's an [example](https://github.com/madskristensen/VisibilityConstraintsSample) of how simple that can be), but there are also some [term types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-rule-based-ui-context-for-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022#term-types) related to *projects* that might be more useful for this scenario.